# MediaWiki Problem

Tags: mediawiki

I can't implement MediaWiki on my website. I made a database called soulz_wikipedia. When I configure my wiki, to install it, it asks me what languages etc to choose from, when I press Continue I can't do anything else. All it comes up with is:

```
MediaWiki 1.17.0 installation

Language
Existing wiki
Welcome to MediaWiki!
Connect to database
Upgrade existing installation
Database settings
Name
Options
Install
Complete!

Restart installation
Welcome to MediaWiki!

Environmental checks
Basic checks are performed to see if this environment is suitable for
MediaWiki installation. You should provide the results of these checks
if you need help during installation.
PHP 5.3.6 is installed.
Unable to determine IP
Backtrace:
0 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/User.php(1537): wfGetIP()
1 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/db/Database.php(683): User->getName()
2 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/db/DatabaseSqlite.php(147): DatabaseBase->query('CREATE VIRTUAL ...', 'DatabaseSqlite:...', true)
3 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/installer/Installer.php(636): DatabaseSqlite::getFulltextSearchModule()
4 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/installer/Installer.php(387): Installer->envCheckDB()
5 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/installer/WebInstallerPage.php(369): Installer->doEnvironmentChecks()
6 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(250): WebInstaller_Welcome->execute()
7 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/mw-config/index.php(46): WebInstaller->execute(Array)
8 /home/soulz/public_html/Wiki/mw-config/index.php(14): wfInstallerMain()
9 {main}
```

That's all, I can't install it.. Help?

Comment: I really don't understand why this doesn't work..

Comment: "Unable to determine IP" ... sounds clear to me.  Something wrong with your setup?

Comment: What do you mean? I set it up accordingly to the guide on installing it. Why won't it work?

Comment: Still having trouble..

Comment: What is returned when you run the following in a PHP file: `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>` ..?

Answer (score 3):

**Fix Method 1**

Update your [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) to the latest version and this resolves this problem.

**Fix Method 2**

If you prefer to use an outdated version then this will fix this problem. Edit `includes/ProxyTools.php`, after line 70 `wfGetIP()`. After `static $ip`:

```
{
$ip = "10.10.10.10";
return $ip;
}
```

Change `10.10.10.10` to the same IP address of your external internet one. IFCONFIG will reveal this for you.